# Deconvolving the convolution of two identical functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution, deconvolution

I want to deconvolve $p(x)$ from the following expression:

$$f(x) = (p\cdot p)(x)$$

where $f(x)$ and $p(x)$ are both real functions. Additionally,

- $f(x)$:

  - has odd symmetry
  - $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\infty$
  - $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{df}{dx}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\dfrac{df}{dx}=1$
- $p(x)$:

  - has even symmetry
  - $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}p(x)=1$
  - $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{dp}{dx}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\dfrac{dp}{dx}=0$

Currently, I'm trying to use Fourier transforms, i.e.:

$p(x) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left\{\sqrt{\dfrac{-j}{\omega}\left[\mathcal{F}\left\{\dfrac{df}{dx}-1\right\}+\delta(0)\right]\right\}$

But is there an easier way? Am I missing some obvious convolution identities?

Comment: What do you mean by "easier way"? You have an explicit formula for $p(x)$. Why is it not good enough?

Comment: Edit statement (p(x)=...).  It is hard to read!